# Weird line ending conversion (CR, LF, CRLF) with istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifstream(..., ios::binary))

Tags: c++, visual-c++, binary-data, ifstream, line-endings

I'm writing a CRC32 routine in MSVC++2010 and need to read a file in binary mode, byte by byte.

I'm doing it with `ifstream` and `istreambuf_iterator`, and it generally works, but it does some weird things to line endings.

For example, if I have a file with the contents

```
LF LF LF CR CR CR
```

the output of my program is

```
 (10) (10) (13) (13) (13) (13)
```

so basically, it replaced the last LF with a CR. Strange.

If I have

```
CR CR LF CR
```

it's

```
 (13) (10) (13) (13)
```

so it swapped the CRLF! It also swaps them when there are more in the file.

Is there any workaround? I'd like to stick to C++ for this and I actually want to read binary files with no interpretation of line endings whatsoever (and I thought only `istream_iterator` would do that)!

---

Just for completeness, the testing code I have is this, adapted from [pyCRC](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/index_en.html):

```
static inline crc_t crc_update(crc_t                          crc, 
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char> data, 
                               long long                      data_len)
{
    unsigned int tbl_idx;
    while (data_len--) 
    {
        tbl_idx = (crc ^ *data) & 0xff;
        crc = (crc_table[tbl_idx] ^ (crc >> 8)) & 0xffffffff;

        data++;

        std::cout << " (" << int(*data) << ")";
    }
    return crc & 0xffffffff;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream file(argv[1], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    struct _stati64 filestats;
    errno_t stat_error = _stati64(argv[1], &filestats);
    if (stat_error != 0)
        return errno;
    std::cout << crc_finalize(
                      crc_update(crc_init(),
                                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
                                 filestats.st_size));
}
```

Comment: How does this even compile? You're passing a temporary `istreambuf_iterator<>` and binding it to a non-const reference...

Comment: @ildjarn: Sorry, I don't understand what's wrong with it. The `istreambuf_iterator` is on the stack there and won't lose scope while `crc_update` runs. And why should it be `const`? Exactly what should a conforming compiler show me? Anyway, the results are the same without the `&`.

Comment: It's illegal to bind a temporary to a non-const reference. A conforming compiler will yield an error on the call to `crc_update`. Passing by value is the correct approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the last LF with CR is missing, it is the first LF in the file is missing, as you did `data++;` before `std::cout << " (" << int(*data) << ")";`

Tried it myself and it isn't missing anything ...

btw: I'm using g++.

Comment: LOL ... man do I feel stupid, this is the price of programming at night :(